# Cannot FTP in ubuntu server

Tags: server, ftp, vsftpd

I have installed ubuntu on a Virtual Machine on my mac to run a website from home.  I followed the Digital Ocean Tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04) to install apache, then mysql and finally php.

I have installed vsftpd as per the instructions in [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04) but for the life of me cannot get to my server from a browser within the host MAC.

I have managed to get the "website" working on the server (wordpress) but whatever I do, I can't get to anything via FTP.  I can't get webmin to work either, but strangely enough, phpMyAdmin works great. I can also get to the site and the admin section of the site too.

Please help, this has been driving me nutts for the past 48 hours, and I"m still no further with it.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and don't use the abomination that is FTP. We now have SFTP (*i.e.*, file transfer over SSH), which is a million times better in every way.

Comment: Sorry, fkraiem that is what I am trying to use.  VSFTPD.  I think the answers lie in my permissions.  Looking at /var/www permissions for owner group are set to root:root, I'm looking into the ideals for wordpress.

Comment: Well then have fun! When you have pulled all your hair out you might reconsider.

Comment: I already have no hair.  I've pulled it all out over the last two days.  I can't ssh at the moment.  I'm just looking into that.

Comment: `cannot get to my server from a browser within the host MAC`. You want ot connect to the FTP server using host MAC-address. Is that correct?

Comment: The server is running in a virtual machine on my iMac.  I am trying to use ubuntu server to serve a website www.morleyhandyman.com however, I cannot change the theme because wordpress needs ftp access.  I'm not bothered how I do it.  Just need to get some sort of file system working.  I've just asked a question on here about SSH.  Sorry, I'm a total newbie to this.